# convert formula to pinescript for tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

`(c/c1>=1.04 and v>v1 and v>=100000)` is the formula that I am trying to convert to pinescript but couldn't where

- latest close(price) is 4% more than the previous day price(rate of change ROC)
- latest volume is greater than previous day volume (relative volume)
- volume is greater than 100000

I cant put these together to get a bar on chart where if all conditions are met a bar appears.
Attached below the separate formulas but I need a way to get it in pinescript where all conditions fulfill together.

```
//RVOL
RVOLlen = input(2, minval=1, title="RVOL Length")
av = sma(volume, RVOLlen)
RVOL = volume / av

plot(RVOL, title="RVol", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, transp=100)

//ROC
ROClen = input(1, minval=1, title="ROC Length")
src = input(close, title="ROC Source")
roca = roc(src, ROClen)


plot(roca, title="RoC", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2, transp=0)
//Bands
hline(4, title="Level 0", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=1, editable=true)
hline(10, title="Level 1", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=1, editable=true)
hline(-4, title="Level 2", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=1, editable=true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to request data from other timeframes.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

[close_prev_day, vol_prev_day] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", [close[1], volume[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

x = ((close / close_prev_day) > 1.04) and (volume > vol_prev_day) and (volume > 100000)

plotshape(x)
```

Comment: what can i say. you are a savior. Thank you very much.